# How to install Windows / Linux Any OS In a VM without affecting the performance or encrypting the drive/partition

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, multi-boot, encryption, hyper-v

##### Hello , (:

***A Backstory :***

I Installed *2 Windows OS's* on  laptop
and I was looking for a way to get that native performance and separate the two OS's At the same time can I came on an question here on Superuser about separating the two OS's by encrypting the drives/partitions that windows installed on , and it should separate the two OS's from each other , let's say if WINDOWS 1 got infected WINDOWS 2 will remain uninfected

In short it did work for the meantime

anyways , some say -  "just use VM's" , and I did use them but I didn't like how laggy and slow the OS's was on the VM

**My Question is :**

Is it possible to run VM's on native machine performance ?
I did a bit of research and there's something called hypervisor but mostly it used for server not laptops or a work station machine

Is what I'm askin possible ? if so I'd love to learn more

I like VM's it's much better to use than installing windows and then encrypting the drive for every OS install to separate them but as I said the only down side for me is the performance

Comment: This should be clear to me.. but I still not understanding exactly what you are saying regarding the encryption.  Would you mind clarifying even further for dummy me :) ?  The reason I am asking more than any other is that I don't see a major performance degradation in my VMs.. but I don't encrypt my volumes either.  Also, because of the jenkey RDC access to the hyper-v volumes, I find that VirtualBox feels more native while I am in a full screen VM.

Comment: it's my fault I didn't explain it correctly in the first place I'd , my apologies (: , what I was trying to say is i have two disks on my machine Disk1 and Disk2 , and I wanted to isolate the both disks from each other to let's say Disk1 as a sandbox for games and home , and Disk2 for more sensitive information/work , and what i did is I encrypted both the disks using bitlocker so when I boot into Disk1 , that disk doesn't have access to Disk 2

Comment: Bitlocker will seriously degrade your performance (as will all encryption technologies).  If it were me (and it isn't), I would keep my business/work stuff inside of a VM and keep backup copies of the entire disk image.  I would keep the "outer OS" for running my games and my VMs and the games are where the real horsepower is needed.  I would sandbox the other way around.

Comment: If you are trying to ensure being able to recover your work.. keep the VMs on a different volume/disk.  You could even be anal and only mount those volumes when you working.  Also, bitlocker being installed makes ransomware attacks possible.